# List with dynamic size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make a list that in up to 6 items, get the full width of the screen by following the following steps:

1. If you have only one item in the list, it takes 100% of the screen
   width;
2. If you have two items in the list, each has to take 50% of the total
   width of the screen;
3. If you have three items in the list, each has to pick up 33% of the
   total width of the screen, and so on up to 6 items.

Follow the code of what I have done so far, I could not do it and I need to do this with CSS only. I'm using Bootstrap.

Follow the link:

https://codepen.io/maur-cio-gabriel-kr-ger/pen/yQQxeN

```css
.linksHome {
  overflow: hidden;
  &__link {
    border: 1px #7e7e7e solid;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 30px 30px 25px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    a {
      float: left;
      padding: 30px 30px 25px 30px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    &:hover {
      opacity: 0.7;
      transition: all 0.2s;
    }
  }
  li {
    &:nth-of-type(odd) {
      .linksHome__link {
        background: #7e7e7e;
        color: white;
        &:hover {
          opacity: 0.7;
          transition: all 0.2s;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="linksHome ui-container-bottom">
  <div class="linksHome__lista w-100">
    <ul class="row m-0 justify-content-center">
      <li class="">
        <a href="" target="_blank" class="w-100">
          <div class="linksHome__link w-100 text-center">
            Link lorem ipsum dolor
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="" target="_blank" class="w-100">
          <div class="linksHome__link w-100 text-center">
            Link lorem ipsum dolor
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="" target="_blank" class="w-100">
          <div class="linksHome__link w-100 text-center">
            Link lorem ipsum dolor
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use $("#myElement li").length
to get the number of available lists

after you can do what you want based on the number of lists available